# Conversion of one XML to another Format using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Can you please help me to convert an xml to another format using xslt? I have an input XML which needs to be converted to another format, However I tried using XSLT, but in vain. Please provide me with a sample code

Here is the below input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncApp xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xyz.com/app/1_0 Application_1_0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/app/1_0" xmlns:env="http://www.xyz.com/group/common/1_0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<env:AppArea>
    <env:Sender>
        <env:LogicalID>String</env:LogicalID>
    </env:Sender>
    <env:Receiver>
        <env:LogicalID>String</env:LogicalID>
    </env:Receiver>
    <env:CreationDateTime>2001-12-17T09:30:47Z</env:CreationDateTime>
    <env:BODID>String</env:BODID>
    <env:UserArea>
        <env:BooleanValue name="String">true</env:BooleanValue>
    </env:UserArea>
</env:AppArea>
<Data>
    <Sync>
        <env:ActionCriteria>String</env:ActionCriteria>
        <env:UserArea>
            <env:BooleanValue name="String">true</env:BooleanValue>
        </env:UserArea>
    </Sync>
    <App>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <NameShort>Test2</NameShort>
        <NameLong>Test1</NameLong>
        <Description>Test</Description>
        <UserArea>
            <env:BooleanValue name="String">true</env:BooleanValue>
            <env:DateTimeValue name="String">2001-12-17T09:30:47Z</env:DateTimeValue>
        </UserArea>
    </App>
</Data>
</SyncApp>
```

And output should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncApp>
<App Name="Test2" TypeNum="6" MDIDTest="1234">
  <AttrDef Name="MDID">
     <AttrValue Value="1234"/>
  </AttrDef>
  <AttrDef Name="LongName">
     <AttrValue Value="Test1"/>
  </AttrDef>
  <AttrDef Name="Description">
     <AttrValue Value="Test"/>
  </AttrDef>
</App>
</SyncApp>
```

Please find the XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <SynchFromXtoY>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SyncApp"/>
    </SynchFromXtoY>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="SyncApp">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Data"/>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="App"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="App">
<App>
    <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="NameShort"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="TypeNum">
        <xsl:value-of select="'6'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>        
    <xsl:attribute name="MDIDTest">
        <xsl:value-of select="MDID"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <AttrDef>
       <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="'MDID'"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <AttrValue>
         <xsl:attribute name="Value">
         <xsl:value-of select="MDID"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
       </AttrValue>
    </AttrDef>
    <AttrDef>
       <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="'LongName'"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <AttrValue>
         <xsl:attribute name="Value">
         <xsl:value-of select="NameLong"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
       </AttrValue>
    </AttrDef>
    <AttrDef>
       <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Description'"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <AttrValue>
         <xsl:attribute name="Value">
         <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
       </AttrValue>
    </AttrDef>
  </App>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance.

BR/Srinivas.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the XSLT you have tried so far? It might be you were very close to a solution, and it only needs a tweak to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Hi TIM,

Please find my code added in the post.

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually far off the solution. The problem you have is mainly with namespaces. In your XML you have this code...

```
<SyncApp xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/app/1_0" ....
```

This is a declaration for a default namespace, which means any elements in your XML that does not have a prefix (like "SyncApp" itself, and "Data" and "App") all belong to this default namespace.

However, in your XSLT there is no mention of this namespace at all. This means that when you do this...

```
<xsl:template match="SyncApp">
```

This is looking for an element called "SyncApp" that is in no namespace. This is a different element to one named "SyncApp" that does belong to the namespace. The namespace is really part of the element name here.

What you need to do is declare the namespace in your XSLT, like so (the prefix you use can be anything, it is the URI that has to match)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                 xmlns:app="http://www.xyz.com/app/1_0"
```

Then, in any xpath expression where you refer to elements in your XML, you must prefix them with the namespace prefix

```
<xsl:template match="app:SyncApp">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:app="http://www.xyz.com/app/1_0"
     xmlns:env="http://www.xyz.com/group/common/1_0"
     exclude-result-prefixes="app env">

<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <SynchFromXtoY>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="app:SyncApp"/>
    </SynchFromXtoY>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="app:SyncApp">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="app:Data"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="app:Data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="app:App"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="app:App">
 <App Name="{app:NameShort}" TypeNum="6" MDIDTest="{app:MDID}">
    <AttrDef Name="MDID">
       <AttrValue Value="{app:MDID}" />
    </AttrDef>
    <AttrDef Name="LongName">
       <AttrValue Value="{app:NameLong}" />
    </AttrDef>
    <AttrDef Name="Description">
       <AttrValue Value="{app:Description}" />
    </AttrDef>
  </App>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note the use of Attribute Value Templates here to simplify the XSLT. Instead of writing this

```
   <AttrValue>
     <xsl:attribute name="Value">
       <xsl:value-of select="app:Description"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
   </AttrValue>
```

You can write this...

```
<AttrValue Value="{app:Description}" />
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.